# Can I display alternate text in my div if {{ user.userName }} is null?

Tags: angularjs

In my text I have the code:

```
<div>{{ user.userName }}</div>
```

Is there a way I can make this display the message "Please login" if user.userName is null. Note I would like to code this business logic in the client not the controller.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<div>{{ user.userName || 'alternate text' }}</div>
<br>
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

</head>

<body ng-controller="test">

  <span>{{user.name || "alt text"}}</span>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module("app", []);

    app.controller("test", function($scope) {});

    angular.bootstrap(document, ["app"]);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What to do if user is null, what to do in that case?

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in several ways:

```
<div>{{ methodForTextDisplay(user.userName) }}</div>
```

Or:

```
<div>{{user.userName || "some default text"}}</div>
```

Or:

```
<div ng-show="user.userName" >{{ user.userName }}</div>
<div ng-show="!user.userName" >Default text</div>
```

Comment: Your first solution goes against the desire to "code the logic in the client not the controller", your second solution is a duplicate of mine.

Comment: I don't think that client is the correct term, I'd use template or view instead.

Comment: @mccainz depends of your requirements and amount of options to display first variant still useful. Second variant I posted because I didnt saw your comment. You posted your variant just before me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-if="user.userName">{{user.userName}}</div>
<div ng-if="!user.userName">Please login"</div>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late, but for the cases where we're testing a boolean, we can do this:

`{{ user.active ? 'Active' : 'inactive' }}`

In your case, we can do this:

`{{user.userName? user.userName: 'alternate text'}}`